# Multiple clients load distribution with redis

Tags: redis, load-balancing

We are using redis as a queue for asynchronous processing of jobs. One application pushes jobs to redis (lpush), other application reads the redis queue (blpop) and processes the same. We wanted to scale the processing application so we ran two different instances on 2 different machines to process the jobs from queue, but we observed that one instance is taking 70% of the load from queue while other instances processes only a meagre amount. Is there any well defined strategy or configuration in using multiple clients with redis and proper load sharing? Or we have to maintain separate queues for the two instances and push the requests in a round robin manner?

Comment: Can you provide the code used to fetch the job

Comment: Snippet below: jedis = redisConfig.getJedisPool().getResource();
List<String> ret = jedis.blpop(timeout, key); return ret.get(1); key variable is the queue name which is constant

Comment: And what does the system if there is no job in the queue?

Comment: The code i sent you runs in an infinite loop with threads sleeping for 1 second. The application has enough load that they dont remain idle

Comment: If both instance are never running out of work, isn't just a difference in comptutationnal power between the instances

Comment: no, we have the same hardware in both the machines, it is like machine A is getting more out of the queue. The machines are separate from redis box since we thought network delay caused the difference first, but even then one machine is processing higher load

Comment: Identical machines can still have a significant difference in how fast they process given tasks. Clients grabbing jobs is entirely client-side. It is surprisingly not uncommon for some consumers to process more jobs than others. Ultimately you should ask yourself if one processing more than the other is an actual problem, or if it just a curiosity.